# .NET Socket Cannot Detect Disconnect Event under Windows 7

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-7

I'm using System.Nets.Sockets.Socket to play the client side to connect our server. Everything works fine under Windows XP. But recently, our client report that the UI cannot alarm when it disconnect from the server side (by un-plug the network cable) under Windows 7. I've debug this situation, and found this case only happen in Windows7, but under Windows XP, it does work.

Then my question is, why this socket disconnect event hasn't been raised up under Windows 7 but XP do? Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehh, what event?

The only way to be sure that a socket is connected is by sending or receiving.

More info:
http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: Is it sending data the only way? Actually the disconnect event can be detected under Windows XP, but not in Windows 7, i'm wondering if Windows 7 changed something causing this issue

Comment: but at least i haven't find this issue under Windows XP but only in Windows 7. It's strange